# Submitting page with different submits buttons and forms with PHP

Tags: php, html

I can't figure this out alone. I have .html file and in body section I'm importing some .php files using switch. I'm displaying table and I'm navigating on it with POST form. Now I want to add to my navigation bar search input which also will send data by POST. It is located on head tag and when I press the button nothing really happens.

***index.php***

```php
<html>
<head>
    <div class="leftNav">
        <a class="buttonNav" href="index.php?subpage=table&data=session&page=0">Session</a>
        <a class="buttonNav" href="index.php?subpage=table&data=all&page=0">All</a>
    </div>

    <div class="rightNav">
        <?php include 'navbars.php' ?>
    </div>

</head>

<body style="font-family:Verdana;">
    <div class="content">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['subpage']))
        {
            switch($_GET['subpage'])
            {
                case 'table':
                    include 'datatable.php';
                    break;
                default:
                    include 'home.php';
                    break;
            }
        }
        else include 'home.php';
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

***datatable.php***

```php
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if($_POST['search'])
        {
            $filtr = $_POST['filtr'];
            $data = $_GET['data'];
            header("
Location: index.php?subpage=table&data=".$data."&page=0&search=".$filtr);
        }
        else{...}  
    }
       //DISPLAYING TABLE//

        echo("
        </table>
        <form class='nav' method='POST'>");

        $disabled = '';
        if($curr+1 == 1)
            $disabled = "disabled='disabled'";
        echo("<input type='submit' name='f' value='First page' ".$disabled.">
            <input type='submit' name='p' value='Previous page' ".$disabled."> ");

        $disabled = "";
        if($curr == $max)
            $disabled = "disabled='disabled'";
        echo("<input type='submit' name='n' value='Next page' ".$disabled.">
        <input type='submit' name='l' value='Last page' ".$disabled."></form>");
?>
```

***navbars.php***

```php
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['subpage']) && $_GET['subpage'] == 'table')
    {
        echo("
        <form method='POST'>
            <input type='text' name='filtr'>
            <input type='submit' name='search' value='Search'>
        </form>
        ");
    }

?>
```

Comment: This needs to happen in Javascript and you need to combine both fields into the same request.

Comment: @AlexBarker I was trying to avoid using JS as much as I can here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, you will want to use the `action` attribute but you'll want to pass the `$_GET['subpage']` as in:

```
action="<?php if(!empty($_GET['subpage'])) echo '?subpage='.htmlspecialchars($_GET['subpage'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>"
```

---

> Note: I don't see anywhere that you actually send the `$_GET['subpage']` or `$_GET['data']` in your scripts in the first place, so I don't know if that is even being called properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding form action if you are referring to same page,

`action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"`

hope it helps you.

Comment: it actually redirects me to the 'index.php' page.